# Tracking Logged In Wordpress Users, What they read, what they comment on, ect

Tags: wordpress, tracking

So I would like to track what my users do on my wordpress blog once they have logged in. For instance, what post they read and what they commented on, what like liked/tweeted/G+s, and what they shared.

Basically my blog has many different sections and topics, and I would like to accurately email my users with content thats targeting to their interests. So I would like to be able to tell if user john likes the cars section, and user jill read 3 of the gardening section.

I would then need to export this data to my campaigns.

I've noticed http://www.kissmetrics.com/ has seemingly something like this. Does anyone have any experience with this?

Any recommendations is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can try these plugins:

- [UserTracker](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/usertracker/)
- [WP SlimStat](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-slimstat/)

Answer (score 0):

https://premium.wpmudev.org/project/user-activity/

Here's one Plugin that I'm going to go with for this purpose, but it doesn't appear to be as feature rich as others.