# How to track logged in user' s recently read articles in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm having a wordpress website where the users can sign up and maintain an user profile.

Each logged in user has 3 tabs called, recommended posts, recently read posts, and bookmarked posts.

Now in this recently read posts thing, I'm struggling to find a way to track the posts read by a certain user..

What is the best way to track user's recently read posts without using any plugin? Any little guide will be highly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

The mentioned duplicate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492377/tracking-logged-in-wordpress-users-what-they-read-what-they-comment-on-ect) has suggested a plugin as a solution to track the posts,but I am willing not to go for a plugin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tracking Logged In Wordpress Users, What they read, what they comment on, ect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492377/tracking-logged-in-wordpress-users-what-they-read-what-they-comment-on-ect)

Answer (score 0):

Cookies *could* work, but it would be unreliable and be bound to the browser, not the account itself. You'd be better off managing a user meta field relatively easily using [`update_user_meta()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta). If you put this somewhere in your loop, or on the template for posts you want to track, it should get you started. You could even put it in your functions file fired on single-post specific hooks, whatever works best for your site layout.

```
if( is_user_logged_in() ){
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    // Return "false" or an array of recent post ID's.
    if( $recently_read = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'recently_read', true ) ){
        // Insert the current post ID to the front of the array
        array_unshift( $recently_read, get_the_ID() );

        // Tracking limit if you want it, by slicing anything beyond the limit off.
        $tracking_limit  = 5;
        $new_recent_list = array_slice( $recently_read, 0, $tracking_limit );
    } else {
        $new_recent_list[] = get_the_ID();
    }

    // Save the new array to the user_meta field.
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'recently_read', $new_recent_list );
}
```

Note that, as written this will allow for duplicate posts, you could combine some `if( !in_array( get_the_ID(), $recently_read) ){}` logic in there pretty easily.

Now you can get an array of post ID's really easily wherever you want by using

[`get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'recently_read', true )`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta)

For example:

```
$recent_ids = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'recently_read', true );

$recent_query = new WP_Query([
    'post__in' => $recent_ids;
]);

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo get_the_title();
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```